# Manejo de errores

Tags: typescript, vscode, class

Me gustaría crear una clase tipo ts en donde se pueda tener únicamente el manejo de errores. Sin embargo, estos se encuentran actualmente dentro de las clases de los controladores:

```
sendVerificationType = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId) as IUser;
        if(user.verified){
            const ALREADY_VERIFIED_MSG = "It exist";
            return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({error: ALREADY_VERIFIED_MSG});
        }
        const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
        await this.sendVerificationTypeAux(user.id,user.type,url);
        return res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).send(ReasonPhrases.OK);
    }
    catch(error){
        return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({error: error});
    }
}
```

Para tener los errores por aparte tuve la idea de crear un padre que fuera:

```
export default abstract class DetailE{
text: any;
title: any;

constructor(){
    this.text = "";
    this.title = "";
}
```

}

en donde se especifique el error, quisiera poder crear un `sendVerificationTypeError` que sea hijo de `DetailE` en donde pueda crear un error para que `sendVerificationType` pueda llamarlo. Esto se debe a que busco seguir un patrón de diseño.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor para casos cuando quieres tener errores personalizados es crear una clase que herede de `Error`, para que con esto puedas tener los [métodos y propiedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) correspondientes a dicha clase. En la documentación de TS puedes encontrar [un ejemplo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-newtarget) de como hacerlo. La documentación es algo vieja (TS 2.2) pero es una "continuación" de los cambios de la versión 2.1 en la que se dan consejos para evitar [problemas al heredar de clases built-in](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work) como `Error`, `Array` y `Map`.

Entonces lo primero es crear una clase base, que en tu caso se llama `DetailE` que heredará de `Error`. Aquí definirás tus propiedades generales, es decir, aquellas que serán compartidas por todos aquellos errores que hereden de `DetailE`.

```js
class DetailE extends Error {
  title!: string;

  constructor(title: string, message?: string) {
    super();

    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, DetailE.prototype);

    if (message) this.message = message;
    if (title) this.title = title;

    this.stack = new Error().stack;
  }
}
```

Luego creas tu error específico, en el que podrás agregar más propiedades de ser necesario.

```js
class sendVerificationTypeError extends DetailE {
  name = 'sendVerificationTypeError';

  constructor(title: string, message?: string) {
    super(title, message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, sendVerificationTypeError.prototype);
  }
}
```

Y la implementación (ya en tu controlador) sería algo así (si necesitas tener un objeto -para poder retornalo como json- podrías usar JSON.stringify(e) para obtener la representación del objeto como texto y no tener inconvenientes para tratar la instancia).

```js
const implementFn = () => {
  throw new sendVerificationTypeError('Título');
}


try {
  implementFn();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  // sendVerificationTypeError: {
  //   "title": "Título",
  //   "name": "sendVerificationTypeError"
  // } 
}
```

Sustituí `text` por `message` porque creo que la finalidad de `text` es precisamente agregar un mensaje sobre el error. Pero te recuerdo que puedes agregar tantas propiedades como necesites sin problemas. En el ejemplo anterior, si proporcionas `message`, al hacer un `cosole.log` del error solo verás el mensaje, pero eso no quiere decir que las demás propiedades no existan. Además al haber heredado de `Error` originalmente puedes acceder a la propiedad `.stack` por ejemplo.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVnjBN).